# How do I Color by Layer?

Tags: reactjs, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I have a react app that is using the forge viewer.  It's running and showing the drawing (dwg file).  My end goal for this task is to get specific layers to change color.  How I'm trying to do that is to find the attribute index for the layer property (similar to the [query tutorial](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/developers_guide/advanced_options/propdb-queries/)) then enum the objects, get their layer property, and if it's the one I want set the theming color as follows:

```
  const color = new THREE.Vector4(25, 25, 25, 25);
  viewer.setThemingColor(dbId, color);
```

I can see that I'm getting a list of objects, but it's telling me `THREE is not defined` and not doing anything.  I've added three.js to my project with `yarn add three-js`.  How do I get it to do this?  Is there a better method than what I'm using?

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something that describes the problem you're having or question you're asking. Your current title is primarily a repetition of information that is already available in the tags. Your title should be clear and descriptive enough to have meaning to a future site user who is skimming through a list of search results trying to find a solution to a problem. Regurgitation of the tags is not meaningful and provides no value. Thanks.

Comment: Updated title, thanks.

Comment: You don't need to repeat the tag information in the title. The tagging system works quite well here and doesn't need help by adding useless noise to the title.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks.

Comment: Hey, just tested with a sample dwg and it works fine (used [this](https://gist.github.com/JoaoMartins-Forge/077d91fe0a9091cd5c97b561ee1a5033) to change colors based on layer name).

You should be able to do that without the need of adding three.js into your project,(not a good practice) as Viewer itself comes with an old version of Three js.

Comment: Trying to follow through that and I think it makes sense, however the code in the link still ends with `const color = new THREE.Vector4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5); changeLayerColor('NAME OF THE LAYER', color);` which still uses `THREE` which is what it's currently telling me it can't find.

Comment: Ok, which version of Viewer you're using? 
If you type THREE.REVISION on console you should get 71 for Viewer V6 and above.
please refer to this link

https://forge.autodesk.com/ja/node/1327

Comment: Should be viewer 7, and yes I get '71' when I type that in the console.

Comment: I'm loading the viewer dynamically from https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/viewer3D.min.js?v=v7.*

Comment: Ok so I'm not sure what changed but suddenly it started recognizing this...  Very confused but it seems to be working now.